# how to know whether the layout is fully inflated in android activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I want to create notification only after the layout has been inflated completely.

[how to know when view has inflated using the onFinishInflate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114772/how-to-know-when-view-has-inflated-using-the-onfinishinflate) reffered this link which says there is no such callback.

```
onFinishInflate()
```

And also simply setting the notification after `setContentView()` won't make it as expected, Notification is shown first then the view is inflated in user view point.

Can Anybody help me out to know ?

Comment: I have posted solution for your problem. Let me know is it helpful to you or not?

Comment: Why do you want to know when the layout has been drawn, what do you want to do then?

Comment: as i mentioned in question i want to give a notification :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not get to know this so i used postDelayed(), to post my notification after some time :)
There is no such callback methods to know this :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainLinear);
ViewTreeObserver vtobs = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 

vtobs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        Log.v("SimpleTest", "Width : "+width);
        Log.v("SimpleTest", "Height : "+height);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: have you called your `notification` from `onGlobalLayout` method?

Comment: ya :) even i hav a seekbar in layout, so wenever i drag it notification s going which is unwanted :(